# Only one value insert in all columns in databse

Tags: php, mysql

```
require_once 'core.php' ;

try {
 $db = new PDO("mysql:host=$host;dbname=$dbname",$user,$password) ;
 $db -> setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE,PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

 $a = array(
    'name' => 'rocky',
    'password' => '12345' ,
    'age' => '22'
    ); 
 $c = implode(",",array_keys($a) ) ;
 $f = ":".implode(" , :",array_keys($a));

  $db->beginTransaction();
  $query = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO try ($c) VALUES ($f)");
  foreach ($a as $key => $value) {
        $query->bindParam(":".$key,$value,PDO::PARAM_STR) ;
  } 
  $query->execute() ;
  $db->commit() ;


} catch(PDOException $e){
die($e->getMessage()) ;
}
```

in database only one which is age value insert  in name ,password, age column same value like 22 ,22 ,22

Comment: Query also  need to run in the loop

Comment: @RakeshSharma  you mean prepare statement in foreach loop

Comment: yes , run your statement in loop

Comment: @RakeshSharma  new errror: Invalid parameter number: number of bound variables does not match number of tokens

Comment: echo your sql-query and count numbers of placeholders.

Comment: try to echo `$f = ":".implode(" , :",array_keys($a)); looks wrong
`

Comment: @u_mulder echo is INSERT INTO try (name,password,age) VALUES (:name , :password , :age)

Comment: @RakeshSharma $f is  right

Comment: Please show us improved code.

Comment: Never execute a query inside a loop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem is in `bindParam` function:

```
$db->beginTransaction();
$query = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO try ($c) VALUES ($f)");
foreach ($a as $key => $value) {
    $query->bindParam(":".$key,$value,PDO::PARAM_STR) ;
} 
$query->execute() ;
$db->commit() ;
```

Reading `bindParam` manual:

> Unlike `PDOStatement::bindValue()`, the variable is bound as a reference and will only be evaluated at the time that `PDOStatement::execute()` is called.

This means that when you do `execute` - all binded variables are set to 
last `$value` value which is the last value of array and is `22`.

So, use `bindValue`:

```
$db->beginTransaction();
$query = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO try ($c) VALUES ($f)");
foreach ($a as $key => $value) {
    $query->bindValue(":".$key, $value, PDO::PARAM_STR) ;
} 
$query->execute() ;
$db->commit() ;
```